# Fitting an RNN estimator in tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a TF estimator using the `RNNEstimator()` class, but I'm having trouble with defining the estimator. My goal is the following:

1. Create a tf.data.Dataset.
2. Feed it into the RNN estimator.

The first part seems to be working correctly. I define the

```
def _parse_func(record):
    # takes tf record as input and returns the following tensors
    # numeric_tensor.shape = (5,170) and y.shape=()
    return {'numerical': numeric_tensor,}, y

def input_fn(filenames=['data.tfrecord']):
    # Returns parsed tf record i.e. the tf.data.Dataset
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=filenames)
    dataset = dataset.map(map_func=_parse_func)
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
    return dataset
```

*Now let's move onto the meaty part*.

Estimators take care of creating the session and graph. So I simply create the estimator in the following format:

```
# create the column
column = tf.contrib.feature_column.sequence_numeric_column('numerical')

# create the estimator
estimator = RNNEstimator(
    head=tf.contrib.estimator.regression_head(),
    sequence_feature_columns=[column],
    num_units=[32, 16], cell_type='lstm')

# train the estimator
estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=100)
```

However, this doesn't work. It gives me a variety of errors! In particularly, at the moment I get:

> TypeError: Input must be a SparseTensor.

Additionally, I seem to be unable to change the loss to log-loss. I tried setting it by passing it to the head parameter using:

`head = tf.contrib.estimator.regression_head(loss_fn=tf.losses.log_loss)`

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm getting the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56920810/unable-to-use-canned-tensorflow-rnn-estimator

Comment: @dippynark No, I haven't. Since tf 2.0 I started moving the code to keras and that's what I use now.

Comment: great, I will try that